# Connect to mongodb using logstash Jdbc_streaming filter plugin

Tags: mongodb, logstash, mongo-java-driver, logstash-jdbc, mongo-jdbc-driver

I'm trying to fetch data from mongodb using Jdbc_streaming filter plugin in logstash in windows.
I'm using **mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar** to connect to the database but, getting a error like this.

```
JavaSql::SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mongo://localhost:27017/EmployeeDB
```

No any luck with existing references. I'm using logstash 7.8.0 version. This is my logstash config:

```
jdbc_streaming {
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:/Users/iTelaSoft-User/Downloads/logstash-7.8.0/mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mongodb.MongoClient"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongo://localhost:27017/EmployeeDB"
        statement => "select * from Employee"
        target => "name"
    }
```

Comment: Try putting the driver jar in the principal folder. (C:/Driver).
I faced the same type of error then reinstalled the jdbc driver for mongo.

Comment: @Max - Thanks for the reply. I tried but, no luck. I got the same error.

Comment: Obviously it is something with the jar controller, never use logstash in windows with which I do not know if it is an official controller or one that you use, but perhaps with this link you can give your problem: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/mongodb-logstash-integration-solved/122299

Comment: I tried almost all the solutions on their forum. Nothing worked. Any way, thanks for the forum link. I will try putting the issue on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try as follows:

1. download https://dbschema.com/jdbc-drivers/MongoDbJdbcDriver.zip
2. unzip and copy all the files to the path(~/logstash-7.8.0/logstash-core/lib/jars/)
3. modify the .config file

Example:

```
input {
  jdbc{
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
    jdbc_driver_library => "mongojdbc2.1.jar"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pwd"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/EmployeeDB"
    statement => "select * from Employee"
  }
}

output {
    stdout { }
}
```

Comment: Wow It worked. I spent 2 days on it. Thank you. But I had to put the full path for driver jdbc_driver_library as follows:

jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Users\iTelaSoft-User\Downloads\logstash-7.8.0\logstash-core\lib\jars\mongojdbc2.1.jar"